# Calculating the probability of a random variable Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, independence, exponential-distribution

I have been really stuck on trying to solve part b of the following question. I have tried calculating the new mean of the distribution as 5.2213 but I don't know where to go from there in terms of how the 4 out of 16 phone impacts the result.[The question/answer is located at the following link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlLHD.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: The link does not work for me either. Probably our firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part is about a binomial distribution $X \sim B(n,p)$ with $n=16$ and $p = 0.2497$. 
Instead of Matlab I used Wolfram Alpha:

[image: Solution Part 2]